# ASP.NET web development with C#. Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session, web-deployment

I am new to ASP.NET and C#. I am trying to create a user registration page with the following steps

1) I am sending a string to session and then redirecting to a login page:

```
protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fn = fullname.Text;
    string em = email.Text;
    string pass1 = password.Text;
    string pass2 = password2.Text;

    if (pass1 == pass2)
    {
       // con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ewadb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
     //   data = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO user_login (fullname, email, password, registered_date) VALUES ('" + fn + "','" + em + "','" + pass1 + "','')", con);
    //   dset = new DataSet();
     //  data.Fill(dset);

        Session["publicmessage"] = "Success";

        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
    else { 
    }
}
```

2) then I try to catch the value from session in to `login.aspx` page

```
        <% if (Session["publicmessage"] = "Success")
           { %>
        <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Registation Success. Please Login!</div>
                </div>
             </div>
            <% } else {}%>
```

I get the error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

Can anyone help me to fix this error, please?

Comment: `Session["publicmessage"]`  is an object, try to extract value and compare

Comment: Don't forget single equals sign if for assignment, double equals sign is used for equality comparisons. See "Value Equality" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save anything in Session, it is saved as object. Here you need to cast it to string. Change this:

```
 <% if (Session["publicmessage"] = "Success")
```

to this

```
  <% if (Session["publicmessage"].ToString() == "Success")
```

Or even better:

```
  <% if (Session["publicmessage"] != null && Session["publicmessage"].ToString() == "Success")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a `NullReferenceException` if it doesn't exist? I would rather use `(string)Session["publicmessage"]`

Answer (score 1):

All of the provided answers are correct. However, when you attempt to read a session variable you should ALWAYS evaluate it for null values for many reasons, especially because session can expire. So instead of doing this...

```
if (Session["publicmessage"] = "Success")
```

do this...

```
if (Session["publicmessage"] != null && Session["publicmessage"].ToString() == "Success")
```

or this...

```
if (Convert.ToString(Session["publicmessage"]) == "Success")
```

Now, design-wise...you shouldn't need to use session to store authentication details. You should ALWAYS try to avoid using session. In this case you should be using cookies instead.